# For what values of $x$ does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x+x^n}{1+x^n}$ exist?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

For what values of $x$ does the following limit exist?
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x+x^n}{1+x^n}$$
Here, $n$ is a natural number.

What I have tried so far:
The limit exists for $x=1$, since the function simplifies to a constant ($=1$).
Further, the limit exists for $x>1$ and the limit equals one in this case. For $x \in (-1,1)$, the limit exists and is equal to $x$.

I am getting confused about the remaining cases ($x\leq-1$). Is the limit undefined for $x\le-1$?

Comment: I would consider the cases $$|x|<1,x>1,x<-1$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner and $x=1$.

Comment: Yes also this case must be considered.

Comment: $\frac{x+x^n}{1+x^n}=1+\frac {x-1}{1+x^n}$ so.......

Comment: @Piquito Rewriting it like this helps a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|x|<1$ we get
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x+x^n}{1+x^n}=x$$
For $x=1$ we get $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x+x^n}{1+x^n}=1$$
For $x<-1$ we get $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+x^n}{1+x^n}=1$$
And for $x=-1$ we get $$\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{-1+(-1)^n}{1+(-1)^n}$$ and the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{x+x^n}{1+x^n}=1+\frac {x-1}{1+x^n}$$

The only problem point is $x=-1$ for which the denominator is $0$ for odd values of $n$

Otherwise the limit is found with little effort.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=-1$, $\frac{x+x^n}{1+x^n}$ is $0$ if $n$ is even but undefined if $n$ is odd, so the limit doesn't exist in that case. If $x<-1$, $|x|>1$ so the function is asymptotically $1$, as in the case $x>1$. (This only works if $n$ is restricted to positive integers, so that we obtain the limit of the sequence, unless for $n\notin\Bbb N$ we use a complex definition of $x^n$.)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the limit as 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x(x^{-n})+1}{x^{-n}+1}
$$so that if $|x|>1$, then $|x^{-1}|<1$ whence using the fact that $r^n\to 0$ for $|r|<1$ we have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x(x^{-n})+1}{x^{-n}+1}=1
$$
for $|x|>1$.

Comment: And $x=1$ or $x=-1$?

Comment: OP Addressed the case $x=1$. Others have addressed $x=-1$